# see the contact's meetings

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am on Odoo 12, my question is quiet simple. how can I see the meetings that belongs to one contact?

as you can see here, that for this contact, I have 2 meetings.

[image]

What I expect, is that it will show me the 2 meetings that belong to Azure Interior.
But what happens is that it shows all the meetings for all contacts

[image]

is it a bug in Odoo itself? (this screenshots are from odoo runbot, I did not change anything) in Odoo 14 for example it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we click on the `Meetings` button, the [schedule_meeting](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/crm/models/res_partner.py#L51) method is executed to return the [action_calendar_event](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/calendar/views/calendar_views.xml#L305) which did not define a domain to filter meetings, it adds only the default partners to the context.

As it is defined, it will show all active meetings.

You can override the `schedule_meeting` method to filter the contact meetings:

```py
class Partner(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    
    @api.multi
    def schedule_meeting(self):
        action = super(Partner, self).schedule_meeting()
        action['domain'] = [('id', 'in', self.meeting_ids.ids)]
        return action
```

Or use the `meeting_ids` field (Many2many) to show them.